# Create a binary file with an image from c++

Tags: c++, macos, binary, icons

I am writing out a binary file from a cpp program and I have no problem actually reading/ writing this file out. I am doing this on a Mac 10.7, so the file has the typical data-file icon which is a blank-ish white sheet with the upper right corner slightly folded in. Now I am trying to change this icon to another image. I have been trying to find some information about this online, but I cant even find out if this is actually possible. Has anybody ever done this before? Or if anyone has any information that could shed light on this, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your application's `Info.plist` file to tell the system what icon file to use for your particular document type.

In particular, you want to read about [CFBundleTypeIconFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW9).

Comment: So I tried doing that and added  Document type with its relevant information, and also added a Exported UTI. But I am still not getting my written out file to have the icon that I want. It still has the text file icon. I specifically dont want anybody to assume that this file can be opened with a text editor. Do I need a NSDocument class to read/write this file? I have been looking at that class but its not very clear if its useful to me.

Comment: I don't think so - as long as your bundle is set up correctly (and you run the program so the OS notices), you should be good.

Comment: I am trying to post a screenshot here, but can't figure out how. But anyways, I have the icon field set up for the document type, and the role as editor. Also its checked to be a bundle. I am not sure what i am missing

Comment: I meant your application bundle.  Are your files bundles, too? (You may need more rep before you can post a screenshot).

Comment: You raise an interesting point. I didn't stop to notice that No, my files are not a bundle. So that's the first thing I am going to fix. But other than that, I am not sure how or why the applicaiton's bundle would be set up incorrectly.